# throwing an exception from method call into textbox

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I am trying to have my page call a method and, if it fails, display an error in my mbResult control. However, since my method is a void method, I am having a hard time throwing the exception.  If I throw it from the method end it will not display in my error box.

I have the following code in my my page:

```
try
{
    Facade.AcceptChanges();
} 
catch(FarAlreadyExistsException) 
{
    mbResult.Message = new MessageInfo(FutureActivitiesAlreadyExistsMessage);
    return;
}
```

the accept changes method is this

```
public void AcceptChanges() 
{
    try
    {
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Swallowing exceptions in this way is not a good thing.

Comment: `catch (Exception) { return; }`  This is very bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second try-catch to let the exception get caught in your first catch block:

```
public void AcceptChanges() 
{
    DataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems you should *also* apply the following change:

```
try
{
    Facade.AcceptChanges();
} 
catch(Exception) // according to the documentation, this should be an OptimisticConcurrencyException
{
    mbResult.Message = new MessageInfo(FutureActivitiesAlreadyExistsMessage);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I tryed this but my program stopped at DataContext

Comment: what do you mean by "stopped"? Did you maybe get a different `Exception` than `FarAlreadyExistsException`?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void AcceptChanges() {
            try
            {
                DataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception cause) {
                throw new FarAlreadyExistsException(cause);
            }
        }
```

You don't throw the exception, so you aren't going to catch it in the try-catch of the first method

Comment: swallowing the original Exception is a bad practice. You should pass along the cause as well:       `catch (Exception e) {

                throw new FarAlreadyExistsException(e);

            }`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't handle the exception in `AcceptChanges` if you're not going to do anything. It's just swallowing the error, so your outer `try...catch` block won't see it (and the code in the `catch` block won't get triggered.

Remove the `try...catch` within your `AcceptChanges` method then the catch code in the method that calls it will catch the exception (as long as it's of the correct type.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  This would make a better comment (which someone has already left).

Comment: I'm answering the question of why isn't it thrown. So, i think i have answered the qusetion. (Possibly i ninja edited while you were commenting?)

Comment: Yep.  All you answer said when I commented was "You shouldn't handle the exception in `AcceptChanges` if you're not going to do anything" - which is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @jadarnel27: It's not a comment, it IS the answer. The exception swallowing is what was causing the original questioner's problem.

Comment: @C.McAtackney I respectfully disagree.  When I applied my downvote, this was not an answer - it was a comment.  ***Now*** it is an answer (after ninja-editing), albeit the same as all the other answers.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Fair enough, I didn't see it before its current state :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the generic `try-catch` statement inside the `AcceptChanges()` method. Let the `Exception` that occurs inside `DataContext.SaveChanges()` bubble up to your `try-catch` inside the first section of code.

You should only handle exceptions that you are expecting (unless you really don't care if a piece of code fails). And you should only handle exceptions in the exact places that care about the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are swallowing the exception in `AcceptChanges`.  Remove the `Try;Catch;` in `AcceptChanges` and let it bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't catch the exception in  `AcceptChanges()` then and let first try-catch block handle it.